# GWT Highcharts - disable series animation

Tags: javascript, gwt, highcharts, gwt-highcharts

How do you disable the animation when series are drawn in GWT Highcharts? If I was using Highcharts in JavaScript directly, [this would be the way to do it](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-animation-disabled/). In my GWT code, I have tried the following without success:

```
chart.setOption("/series/animation", false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this approach:

```
final Chart chart = new Chart()
    .setLinePlotOptions( new LinePlotOptions()
                    .setAnimation(false);
  )
```

Of course instead of `setLinePlotOptions` and `new LinePlotOptions()` you need to put a proper subclass of `PlotOptions`